# Zend GData delete events in a range on non-primary calendar

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, zend-gdata

How can I programmatically delete events in a secondary calendar in Google calendar for a specific date range? I have been searching for a few days now and all the tutorials and questions answered so far only show how you can delete on the default calendar. Has anyone got an example of how I can delete events from a non-default calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit odd to answer my own question. But it might help someone else to save a lot of time. The hint was from this [post](http://www.samtseng.liho.tw/~samtz/blog/2010/10/11/howto-delete-non-primary-google-calendar-event/).

Basically, when you are searching for the events to be deleted, how you set the non-default calendar is by changing the setUser part from

> `$query->setUser('default');`

to

> `$query->setUser($UserPartFromSecondaryCalendarID);`

The calendar ID for secondary calendars are in the form of http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/XXXXXXXXXX. What you should be passing for `$UserPartFromSecondaryCalendarID` is XXXXXXXXXX. This can be easily achieved by splitting the calendar ID by '/' and getting the last element (6).